# SQL getting values that apear once, not distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having touble getting only values that appear once. I currently have some  sql code that gets out the all the entries that have 0 percent. The problem is that two rows can contain the same person With different percentages. If one of these is above 0 then i dont want it to come out in the Query

```
abridged table:
Name - Percent 
steve    0
dan    0
mike    100
harold    50
steve    80
carl    0
carl    0

Result:
dan - 0
Carl - 0
```

Here is how far ive gotten, but not managed to make any variation of Count() or having or Group by working.

```
select person, Value2, Value3, Value4, percent
from 
Table1
INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table2.valueNum = Table1.valueNum 
INNER JOINTable1 ON Table3.valueNum = Table1.valueNum 
INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table4.valueNum = Table1.valueNum 
WHERE 
(@date BETWEEN table1.FROMDATE AND table1.todate) 
AND table1.percent =  0
AND table1.varchar IN ('T',  'X')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example SQL and abridged table don't match. However, this looks like the basic idea you are after:

```
select
  *
from
  dbo.table a
where
  a.percent = 0 and
  not exists (
    select
      'x'
    from
      dbo.table b
    where
      a.Name = b.Name and
      b.percent > 0
  );
```

Comment: Thank you! That was pretty much what i was looking for. I didnt know you could use tables from outside a subquery.

Answer (score 2):

This is one method

```
select name,0 as percent from abridged 
group by name
having min(percent)=0 and max(percent)=0
```

Comment: Since there are no negative percent values, you can remove the min(percent)=0 from the having clause.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use window functions:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by name) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve your problem you can use this query:

```
select [name], 0 as [percent] from [abridged]
group by [name]
having sum([percent])=0
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem right?

```
select name,sum([percent]) from abridged 
group by name
having SUM([percent]) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

**Query**

```
SELECT distinct name,  min(percentage) from a
group by name
having min(percentage) = 0
and count(*) > 1;
```